# How to get all events happening during the next week in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble to avoid failing with leap years. This is my current code:

```
scope :filter_by_birth_date_next_week, -> { joins(:person).where("EXTRACT(week from people.birth_date) = ? and active = ?", Date.today.cweek + 1, true) }
```

This scope finds me birthdays from people born in 2019 but not from people born in 2020, for example.

edit: the basic example would be:

```
person1.birth_date = DateTime.new(2022, 6, 9)
person2.birth_date = DateTime.new(2020, 6, 9)
```

cweek of person1 is 22, cweek of person2 is 23.

I think there may have been some confusion as the birth_date is immutable, it's literally the yyyy/dd/mm a person was born. person2 was born in the ISO86001 22 week of 2020 while person1 was born in the 23 week of 2022. When today is a non-leap day after 28/03, it will compare the cweek of person2 (born in a leap year) with the cweek of a non-leap year.

Comment: Can you add the example?

Comment: `cweek` and `EXTRACT(week`... both implement ISO8601 - and both see the transition from week 9 to week 10 in 2020 as being March 2nd, so no sign there's any misalignment around the leap year.  As Vishal said, you need to show a date that PG and Ruby disagree.

Comment: @smathy I've added the basic example to test this. It's a pretty simple case, in reality it would be as easy as to make a helper method to substract 1 if any of the compared dates is a leap year, but ideally, I'm trying to make something a little bit more enclosed to an one-line scope.

Comment: Neither `person1` nor `person2` would NOT be selected by your scope.